# Android EditText: How to create an empty bullet paragraph by BulletSpan?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring, bulletedlist, spanned

I use the same title with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280528/how-to-create-a-empty-bullet-paragraph-by-bulletspan), because I think my question is very similar to that one, I read and tested the accepted answer very carefully, however the accepted answer doesn't work for me. Let me describe my question:

My code looks like:

```
 EditText myEdit = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.myedit);
 myEdit.setText("a\nb\n");
 Spannable s = myEdit.getText();
 s.setSpan(new BulletSpan(30), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 s.setSpan(new BulletSpan(30), 2, 3,  Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 s.setSpan(new BulletSpan(30), 4, 4,  Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 myEdit.setText(s);
```

What I want to see is:

- a
- b
- *[I want to see the 3rd bullet here, but it doesn't show up]*

I tried `Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE`, `Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE`, `Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE`,`Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE`, but none of these flags works for me.

And if I use these codes:

```
EditText myEdit = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.myedit);
myEdit.setText("a\nb\nc");
Spannable s = myEdit.getText();
s.setSpan(new BulletSpan(30), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
s.setSpan(new BulletSpan(30), 2, 3,  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
s.setSpan(new BulletSpan(30), 4, 5,  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
myEdit.setText(s);
```

Then I get the expected result:

- a
- b
- c

I am working on a rich text editor, when user clicks bullet icon, I need to show an empty bullet, but now I am not sure what the problem might be, as I want to make a new empty BulletSpan (with only a dot, but no chars after it), but if there are no chars in the span's start and end, the dot doesn't show up.

Comment: I currently have a project about rich text editor on Android: https://github.com/chinalwb/are, you can refer to if you need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is an ugly solution, but I have not found any better - try adding an empty character in the end (something like zero-width space). This is producing the result you'd like (at least visually):

```
public void setBulletText(EditText myEdit, String text) {
        String[] lines = TextUtils.split(text, "\n");
        SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        for (int index = 0; index < lines.length; ++index) {
            line = lines[index];
            int length = spannableStringBuilder.length();
            spannableStringBuilder.append(line);
            if (index != lines.length - 1) {
                spannableStringBuilder.append("\n");
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(line)) {
                spannableStringBuilder.append("\u200B");
            }
            spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new BulletSpan(30), length, length + 1,
                Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        myEdit.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
    }
```

The result is:
[image]

Ideally I'd make a custom `EditText` class which appends this character internally, but removes it when the text is being sent to any other object.

Comment: Hmmm... yeah, I can imagine having a `getRawText()` on the subclass that returns `super.getText()` (and leaves the zero-width space), then overriding `getText()` itself to remove that character. I had considered and rejected this basic idea, but I had not thought about the zero-width space, as I was thinking of adding actual whitespace. The zero-width space makes it more palatable. Have you run into any problems with fonts not honoring that particular Unicode character? Many thanks!

Comment: Haven't noticed any issues yet, but I haven't really tested much either. Actually I'm not a big fan of this solution - just haven't found anything better yet. :/

Comment: I have not had a chance to test these answers, and won't before the bounty grace period expires. All three involve putting something on the line for the last bullet. Of the three, this one (IMHO) is the one least likely to introduce visual artifacts, which is why it is getting the bounty. That being said, as I have not tried any of them just yet, YMMV.

Comment: @SamuilYanovski, thanks for this answer, looks good to me, but I'd spend more time to wire it up into my app, I'll come back to update my status. And at CommonsWare, thanks a lot for bring my question brighter so that I can get these answers, I was referring to CommensWare for Rich Text Editor development, but seems it is still a long way to go, and I am on the way :)

Comment: Sorry, I am late. I gave it a test, and it works very well! I am going to open source my rich text editor, which contains a simple list (numeral / bullet) item editing, bold, italic, underline, strike, background color, increase/decrease indent, etc... Hope it can help you and hope you can make enhancements on it too.

Answer (score 2):

Is this good?

```
EditText myEdit = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.myedit);
myEdit.setText("a\nb\n\n");
Spannable s = myEdit.getText();
s.setSpan(new BulletSpan(30), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
s.setSpan(new BulletSpan(30), 2, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
s.setSpan(new BulletSpan(30), 4, 5, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
myEdit.setText(s);
myEdit.setSelection(s.length()-1);
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: If that relies upon the `setSelection()` call, it is not good, insofar as the effect may be lost if the user clicks somewhere.

Comment: since we are setting the text programmatically, without setSelection() the cursor will be just before 'a'. But otherwise, all 3 bullets appear as above.

Comment: you could use setTextKeepState() method

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple solution to this, just add a space at the end of the newline

```
EditText myEdit = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.myedit);
myEdit.setText("a\nb\n "); //notice the space after newline
Spannable s = myEdit.getText();
s.setSpan(new BulletSpan(30), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
s.setSpan(new BulletSpan(30), 2, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
s.setSpan(new BulletSpan(30), 4, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
myEdit.setText(s);
```

Comment: That is basically the same as Samuil's answer, except his has less visual impact. Given how the user clicks on the `EditText`, your space will be actually noticeable (e.g., user clicks and winds up on the end of that last bullet, resulting in a leading space). Thanks, though!

Comment: I tried the code and the space is not noticeable and even if you click the user is at the right place.

Comment: OK, I will run some tests. Thanks!

Comment: ok, when the user drags the cursor to the next row, he can end up with the leading space. But clicking on the bullet point, it shows up at the start