# Solving the empty bulletspan

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've encountered a problem with formatting text in textview/editview. The problem is that if the text ends with a newline, the last line (empty) doesn't use any styles at all. Here's the code that is the reason: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/Layout.java#L1723
It doesn't matter unless the style is something like BulletSpan.

In my case it is exactly this problem - a bulletspan, an empty line and I want that empty span to be rendered. It seems that the only way to solve it is to add a zero-width space at the end of the EditView. ([Android EditText: How to create an empty bullet paragraph by BulletSpan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399111/android-edittext-how-to-create-an-empty-bullet-paragraph-by-bulletspan)) But then I'll have to deal with edits that could possible delete it.

So far the solution I found is to subclass SpannableStringBuilder and return it from my own Editable.Factory for my EditText. My SpannableStringBuilder will have to check if the last character is newline and add a zero-width space in this case. I will have to do that in both constructor and `replace` methods. The problem is - I have no idea what android code will actually do with my editable.

I have actually tried implementing something like that using some "actual"  character and as result I had that character being duplicated, copied, pasted etc. I tried to manage the selection, not allowing SELECTION_START and SELECTION_END to ever be at the end of the text. Still the symbols were randomly duplicating when my edittext was getting or losing focus.

Is there any *sane* and *reliable* method of actually having the empty bullet displayed?

Possible other workarounds that I've tried:

- Artificially drawing the bullet won't help - if the cursor is in the last position, it will be located at the left edge of the edittext, not at BulletSpan's left margin width.
- Having a separate edittext for the last line only will be displaying stuff correctly. But I'll have a problem handling the backspace.
- Subclassing EditText, not Editable - I can't handle selection going past the "trailing" character. Selection is applied directly to editable, not to EditText.