# Android EditText to start each paragraph with a bullet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, string-formatting

I have an EditText in which I want each paragraph to start with a bullet. The EditText itself goes to infinity, so to speak; which means a user can enter as many paragraphs as desired. So how do I get each paragraph to start with a bullet and keep the entire paragraph indented?

Comment: Look here may be it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280528/how-to-create-a-empty-bullet-paragraph-by-bulletspan

Comment: @Mohamed I saw that answer, I didn't understand it. It seems to work when each paragraph has exactly 3 characters. In my case each paragraph can be as long or as short as it needs to be.

Comment: Yes, there is only 3 words in the examples, so you can just adapt it.
When you do line break in your edittext, you should implement onKeyListener and then you add a BulletSpan
yourEditBox.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                // intercept the return key
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });

Answer (score 0):

you probably can do it by using a TextWatcher. I did the same before to add a `@` symbol before the username

```
editor.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) {
       // here you can change the text in the editor
       if(e.charAt(e.length()-1) == '\n') {
           // add the new char you need
           ... here ...
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
       { /* not action */ }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence val, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
       { /* not action */ }
});
```